# depends on before dependency resolution

Tags: gradle

I have to call a task in another module before building this specific project. That's because it's trying to grab a dependency that I have to build and it doesn't exist, throwing an error.

Any idea how I would call a task before dependency resolution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically in gradle you would depend on the result of building the other project. This can be done by adding the project dependency. For example, ProjectA's build.gradle is setup to depend on ProjectB.

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':ProjectB')
}
```

The output of building ProjectB will be put on the classpath of ProjectA when it is compiled. So ProjectB will be built and the dependency should exist before ProjectA is built.